# How to test for location displacement of two replicates with multiple tests?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have success/no success data of reaching a certain location by dummies that were displaced at different distances from that point for two different types of dummy colonies (so two replicates). These two colonies were tested twice, the control is basically with an intact dummy colony hill and after treatment which is with a destroyed hill.

Something like this:

[image]

In a way this seems like an obvious thing to me but I cant figure out how to test the differences between replicate 1 and 2 for the various distances. I also cannot figure out how to test the difference inside each replicate of control vs treatment. Am I building the table wrong? I know it has to be a non-parametric test since I only have count data, I was thinking chi-square or fisher's exact test? But I do not if it is possible to do that if you have two sets of paired replicates.

I hope I managed to be clear and I appreciate any possible help!
Thanks a lot!